# Converter formato da data para MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um software em `C#` e nesse software pedi para informar a data de nascimento do cliente no formato `dd/mm/aaaa`, mas só que no Banco de Dados o tipo data só é aceito no formato `aaaa-mm-dd`, queria saber se existe algum tipo de conversão no banco para ficar do formato que eu desejo

Comment: Coloque o que está fazendo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez melhor que formatar a data, seja utilizar parâmetros na query, evitando assim falhas de segurança do tipo **SQLInjection**

Então, ao invés de concatenar as strings:

```
"UPDATE Clientes SET dataNascimento = " + minhaDataString
```

você pode fazer:

```
"UPDATE Clientes SET dataNascimento = :dataNascimento"

Command.Parameters.Add("dataNascimento", minhaData, SqlDbType.DateTime)
```

Porque independentemente do formato de data do banco de dados utilizado, você deixa o framework fazer o trabalho dele e encapsular esta regra para ti

Comment: Sim, isto é o correto.

Comment: Mas tipo, não a nenhum tipo de conversão no própio MySql ? tipo algum CAST

Comment: O correto para execução de queries é que elas sejam passadas parametrizadas pois isto melhora o desempenho do banco porque ele ira guardar em cache e não ira compilar seu comando sql novamente, e a conversão fica a critério do driver e da linguagem a ser utilizada passar queries concatenando string é errado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o C# formatar para o valor que o MySQL deseja.

```
MinhaData.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Isso no caso de uma vaiável do tipo `DateTime`. Se você tiver apenas a string "dd/mm/aaaa" terá que fazer a conversão para `DateTime` e depois formatar.

```
string Data = "01/01/2016"  
DateTime MinhaData = DateTime.Parse(Data);
```